# How to implement parenthesis and Logical operators using PLY (parser) in Python

Tags: python, parsing, operators, expression

I am trying to implement a parser using PLY. I have created the basic functionalities of numerical operators (+, -, *, /). And I want to implement the parenthesis so that I can give priorities to calculations and also implement the `OR` and `AND` operators. I have tried to use the in the expression function but it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
import ply.lex as lex
import ply.yacc as yacc
import sys
tokens = [
    'INT',
    'FLOAT',
    'NAME',
    'PLUS',
    'MINUS',
    'DIVIDE',
    'MULTIPLY',
    'EQUALS',
    'LPAREN',
    'RPAREN',
    'AND',
    'OR']
t_PLUS = r'\+'
t_MINUS = r'\-'
t_MULTIPLY = r'\*'
t_DIVIDE = r'\/'
t_EQUALS = r'\='
t_LPAREN = r'\('
t_RPAREN = r'\)'
t_AND = r'\&'
t_OR = r'\|'
t_ignore = r' '

lexer = lex.lex()
precedence = (
    ('left', 'PLUS', 'MINUS'),
    ('left', 'MULTIPLY', 'DIVIDE'),
    ('left', 'LPAREN', 'RPAREN'),
    ('left', 'OR', 'AND'))

def p_expression(p):
    '''
    expression : expression PLUS expression
                | expression MINUS expression
                | expression DIVIDE expression
                | expression MULTIPLY expression
                | LPAREN expression PLUS expression RPAREN
                | LPAREN expression MINUS expression RPAREN
                | LPAREN expression DIVIDE expression RPAREN
                | LPAREN expression MULTIPLY expression RPAREN
    '''
    p[0] = (p[2], p[1], p[3])

def run(p):
    global env
    if(type(p)) == tuple:
        if p[0] == '+':
            return run(p[1]) + run(p[2])
        elif p[0] == '-':
            return run(p[1]) - run(p[2])
        elif p[0] == '/':
            return run(p[1]) / run(p[2])
        elif p[0] == '*':
            return run(p[1]) * run(p[2])
        elif p[0] == '=':
            env[p[1]] = run(p[2])
            print(env)
        elif p[0] == 'var':
            if p[1] not in env:
                return 'Undeclared variable found!'
            else:
                return env[p[1]]   
    else:
        return p
```

Can some one help me to implement the parenthesis for example:

when I want to use (1+1)*2 To do the 1+1 first. Like it should be. But also if there are more than one pair of parentheses to do the ones that are outside first and so on. Also how should I implement the logical operators AND and OR?

When I run the code and type: `(1 + 1)` gives me `None`. I guess it's the:

```
def p_empty(p):
    '''
    empty :
    '''
    p[0] = None
```

Because it cannot handle parenthesis?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. [ask]

Comment: @Julien please check again because I really need to solve this...